# View Laravel command logs in docker container

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I'm running a Laravel PHP application as a container on AWS ECS. The container runs both `php-fpm` and `nginx` in the same container.

I didn't write the application, I'm a DevOps guy, but I'm struggling with a `Command` that I added recently to generate a `sitemap.xml`.

The important bits of the application's `Dockerfile` is an `ENTRYPOINT` script which contains this...

```
nginx -g "daemon off;" &

echo "--- Clearing artisan cache"
yes | php artisan config:clear

echo "--- Running migrations"
yes | php artisan migrate

echo "--- Seeding database"
yes | php artisan db:seed

echo "--- Running final container command"
exec "$@"
```

And its `CMD` looks like this:

```
CMD ["php-fpm", "--nodaemonize", "--force-stderr"]
```

The PHP command I C&P'd from the Spatie sitemap generator examples looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Spatie\Sitemap\SitemapGenerator;

class GenerateSitemap extends Command
{
    /**
     * The console command name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'sitemap:generate';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Generate the sitemap.';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        // modify this to your own needs
        SitemapGenerator::create(config('app.url'))
            ->writeToFile(public_path('sitemap.xml'));
    }
}
```

If I `exec` into the running container and run `php artisan schedule:list` I see the following output:

```
  0 0 * * *  php artisan sitemap:generate ........ Next Due: 12 hours from now
```

The container has been running for nearly a week with this command, but if I run `find / -name "sitemap.xml"` I see no results and if I view `mywebsite.co.uk/sitemap.xml` I get no response.

**The main problem I'm having** is that I have no idea how to diagnose any problems with this command. I've got [Sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/) configured correctly (it reports exceptions - but nothing related to this command) and my container logs only appear to show Nginx access logs.

If I navigate through the container's file structure, I can't see any PHP logs at all. I'm wondering if the PHP logs are working as expected, but the command is just failing silently?

Any thoughts on the command itself or the container PHP logs would be greatly appreciated.